# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n} = L$ given that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = L$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n} = L$$

(Also given **HINT**: Let $a>0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{\frac 1n}=1$)
What I have so far:  $$\text{Let}\:\epsilon>0.\:\text{Then}\;\exists\;N\in\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}\;\text{such that}\;n\ge N.$$$$\text{Then}\;L-\epsilon\lt a_n \lt L + \epsilon$$
$$\text{Let}\; b_n =(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n} \text{for}\; n\ge N$$
$$\text{Now}\;b_n = (a_1a_2\ldots a_N)^{\frac 1n}(a_{N+1}\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n}$$
I am struggling with how to use the given hint and maybe limit superior/inferior facts to prove the limit is L. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Also this is my first time using MathJax so please let me know if I have made any mistakes. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm looking specifically on how to prove it using $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ properties!

Comment: Take logs.$\phantom{oooooo}$

Comment: The other question is going for deletion, what happens if you close a duplicate and the other question is deleted?

Comment: Use that $(a_1a_2\ldots a_N)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(a_1)^{\frac{1}{n}}(a_2)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdots(a_N)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and that each term goes to 1.

Comment: If each term goes to 1, how does the limit approach L?

Comment: @clark: Wait, are you claiming that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n c_i = \prod_{i=1}^\infty (\lim_{n\to\infty} c_i)$?

Comment: @anomaly, jokus I am using the notation that the OP is using, there $N$ is a fixed number. So the first $N$ terms go to 1 and the others will go between  $L-\epsilon$ and   $L+\epsilon$

Comment: set $x_n:=\prod_{k=1}^na_k$. Now try to prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exists then it is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}$. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980292/for-x-n0-prove-that-underline-lim-fracx-n1x-n-le-underline-lim-sqrt) also.

Comment: @Masacroso IMO this is a harder problem to do , basically a version of the Cesaro Stoltz lemma. So, if the OP hasn't managed to solve this problem I think it would unlikely to solve the one you are suggesting.

Comment: Juko, each term goes to $1$ but you have infinite terms, which gives the indeterminate form $1^{\infty}$, which in turn can be anything

Comment: See this also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441672/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-sum-limitsk-0n-lambda-k-prod-limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the ideas of limsup and liminf in mind, we can conjure up an alternate approach than given in other answers.

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive sequence such that $a_n\rightarrow L$. Assume, to start, that $L>0$. Choose $\varepsilon$ such that $L>\varepsilon>0$. Then choose $N$ large enough so that for all $n>N$, we have that
$$L-\varepsilon\leq a_n\leq L+\varepsilon\,.$$

Finally, set $M=a_1\ldots a_N$ to save on space. Then we have that
$$\sqrt[n]{M}\sqrt[n]{(L-\varepsilon)^{n-N}}\leq\sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}=\sqrt[n]{Ma_{N+1}\ldots a_n}\leq \sqrt[n]{M}\sqrt[n]{(L+\varepsilon)^{n-N}}\,.$$

The inequalities on the left and right respectively give
$$L-\varepsilon\leq \liminf\sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}\quad\text{ and }\quad \limsup\sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}\leq L+\varepsilon\,.$$

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get our desired limit.

If $L=0$, we needn't worry about the inequality on the left. We can settle for the cruder estimate
$$0\leq \sqrt[n]{a_1\ldots a_n}$$
while still using liminf.

Comment: How do we go from $L-\varepsilon$ to $\sqrt[n]{M}\sqrt[n]{(L-\varepsilon)^{n-N}}$ ? I don't really understand where n-N comes from

Comment: The second line of inequalities is self-contained. I used that $(L-\varepsilon)\leq a_{k}$ for $k=N+1, N+2, \ldots, n$ (for a total of $n-N$ times). The $M$ is just along for the ride.

Comment: Hi sorry for another late question. For the L=0 case, why don't we worry about the left inequality? Don't we have to show $\liminf \ge 0 \;$ using left inequality, and then use the right inequality to show $\limsup \le 0$?

Comment: @Jokus We do worry about the left side, but we use the weaker inequality. $L-\varepsilon$ might be negative, in which case the roots don't make sense. And we use the right inequality to show that $\limsup \leq \varepsilon$ for every positive $\varepsilon$. So, essentially $\limsup\leq 0$, but not directly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n}=e^{\frac{\sum\log a_i}{n}}$$

and by **[Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_i^n\log a_i}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_i^{n+1}\log a_i-\sum_i^{n}\log a_i}{n+1-n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} 
\log a_{n+1}=\log L$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{\frac 1n} = e^{\log L}=L$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to convert the geometric mean to an arithmetic mean. See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220020/limit-of-a-geometric-mean) . Then find the limit of the arithmetic mean. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250474/mean-of-a-convergent-sequence).

Comment: it is a particular case of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441672/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-sum-limitsk-0n-lambda-k-prod-limits

Answer (score 0):

First, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have
$$
L-\epsilon< a_n< L+\epsilon\quad(1)
$$
We know that
$$
\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}\leq(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{n}}{n}\quad(2)
$$
Hence, we have
$$
\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n_0}}+\frac{(n-n_0)}{(L-\epsilon)}}\leq(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{n_0}}{n}+\frac{(n-n_0)}{n}(L+\epsilon)\quad(3)
$$
Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{n_0}}{n}+\frac{(n-n_0)}{n}(L+\epsilon)\right]=L+\epsilon
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n_0}}+\frac{(n-n_0)}{(L-\epsilon)}}{n}=\frac{1}{L-\epsilon}
$$
Then for all $\epsilon>0$
$$
L-\epsilon\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq L+\epsilon
$$